# Samsung Galaxy S3 Aux Cord

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I drive a 2007 Saab 93 without any bluetooth capabilities. I tried to play music with an aux cord and the car senses that my phone is connected but when I try to play any music my phone plays it through the built in speaker and not through the car stereo. I'm just wondering if there is a setting or anything that I need to do in order to play music?

Thanks.

Comment: The car senses the phone, but does the phone sense that there's something in the headphone jack?

Comment: Do normal headphones work? Is the "aux cord" a standard 3,5mm stereo plug or does it have a mic connector too?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the auxiliary jack on my S3 is pretty tight and even when the phone senses I've plugged something into it, I have to press it just a little harder, until I hear a "click" and the plug is flush to the phone (you should not be able to see any metal from the plug showing).  Once I do that, the sound stops playing through the phone's speaker.